# Remove gap between two rectangles in CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I created a menu item with jquery and CSS but is has a gap in menu items..One item is placed on top op other ite..I want to remove this gap and push every eliment right litle by litle as I shown in the image. How can I do that?

here is the image of the menu item...
[image: Menu Item]

here is my CSS file

```
    *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    background:#000;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.oe_overlay{
    background:#000;
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
ul.oe_menu{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    margin:60px 0px 0px 40px;
    width:967px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
ul.oe_menu > li{
    width:112px;
    height:50px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
ul.oe_menu > li > a{
    display:block;
    background-color:#101010;
    color:#aaa;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
    width:138px;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:1px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #000;
    opacity:0.8;
}
ul.oe_menu > li > a:hover,
ul.oe_menu > li.selected > a{
    background:#fff;
    color:#101010;
    opacity:1.0;

}
.oe_wrapper ul.hovered > li > a{
    background:#fff;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #FFF;
}
ul.oe_menu div{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:1px;
    background:#fff;
    width:967px;
    height:180px;
    padding:30px;
    display:none;
}
ul.oe_menu div ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#222;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 4px;
    margin:2px;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
}
ul.oe_menu div ul.oe_full{
    width:100%;
}
ul.oe_menu div ul li a:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
ul.oe_menu li ul{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
li.oe_heading{
    color:#aaa;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

this is my html

```
     <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/Aller.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('ul.oe_menu div a',{hover: true});
            Cufon.replace('h1,h2,.oe_heading');
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            span.reference{
                position:fixed;
                left:0px;
                bottom:0px;
                background:#000;
                width:100%;
                font-size:10px;
                line-height:20px;
                text-align:right;
                height:20px;
                -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 10px #000;
                -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 10px #000;
                box-shadow:-1px 0px 10px #000;
            }
            span.reference a{
                color:#aaa;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-decoration:none;
                margin-right:10px;

            }
            span.reference a:hover{
                color:#ddd;
            }
            .bg_img img{
                width:100%;
                position:fixed;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                z-index:-1;
            }
            h1{
                font-size:75px;
                text-align:right;
                position:absolute;
                right:40px;
                top:20px;
                font-weight:normal;
                /*text-shadow:  0 0 3px #0096ff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #0096ff, 0 0 70px #0096ff, 0 0 80px #0096ff, 0 0 100px #0096ff, 0 0 150px #0096ff;
            */}
            h1 span{
                display:block;
                font-size:15px;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            h2{
                position:absolute;
                top:220px;
                left:50px;
                font-size:40px;
                font-weight:normal;
                /*text-shadow:  0 0 3px #f6ff00, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #f6ff00, 0 0 70px #f6ff00, 0 0 80px #f6ff00, 0 0 100px #f6ff00, 0 0 150px #f6ff00;
*/}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bg_img"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="background" /></div>
        <h1>Duke Fashion<span>Overlay Effect Menu with jQuery</span></h1>
        <h2>Welcome to the world of fashion</h2>

        <div class="oe_wrapper">
            <div id="oe_overlay" class="oe_overlay"></div>
            <ul id="oe_menu" class="oe_menu">
                <li><a href="">Collections</a>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Summer 2011</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Special Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Runway Show</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Winter 2010</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Behind the scenes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Interview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Categories</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Nature Pure</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Swimwear</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Evening</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Projects</a>
                    <div style="left:-111px;"><!-- -112px -->
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Fashion Shows</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Berlin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Events</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fashion Party 2011</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Evening specials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fashion Day Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Model Workshops</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Media</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Wallpapers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contest 2011</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fashion Mania</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Green Earth Day</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Fragrances</a>
                    <div style="left:-223px;">
                        <ul class="oe_full">
                            <li class="oe_heading">Fashion Fragrances</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Deálure</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Violet Woman</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Deep Blue for Men</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York, New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Illusion</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Events</a>
                    <div style="left:-335px;">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Shows 2010</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Berlin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Shows 2011</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Berlin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Special Events</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fashion Party 2011</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fashion Countdown Party 2010</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fashion Day Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Model Workshops</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Stores</a>
                    <div style="left:-447px;">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Europe</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Berlin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Asia</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hong Kong</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tokio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New Delhi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Beijing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">United States</li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Miami</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
               <li><a href="">My table</a>
                    <div style="left:-559px;">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Europe</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Berlin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Asia</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hong Kong</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tokio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New Delhi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Beijing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">United States</li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Miami</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="">Admin</a>
                    <div style="left:-671px;">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Europe</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Berlin</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">Asia</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hong Kong</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tokio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New Delhi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Beijing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="oe_heading">United States</li>
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Miami</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="reference">
                <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/11/25/overlay-effect-menu/">back to the Codrops tutorial</a>
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/duke9042004/" target="_blank">Background image by Duke Photo</a>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: JSFiddle is good for demonstrating your issue with this kind of thing, and without the relevant HTML that this CSS applies to, it might be possible to guess your problem, but not particularly rewarding, and there's also the chance that you may be wrong (about what's relevant) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your page in Firefox with Firebug, or Chrome, or other browser with web developer tools.  Then start modifying margins,padding, etc. using the developer tools.  This is easiest way to troubleshoot CSS problems, as you can see immediate feedback on the page for the changes you make.

Comment: Thanks I got it from fire bug